# Detect when bluetooth device disappears on Android

Tags: android, listview, bluetooth, android-arrayadapter

I'm creating a simple application that will communicate via Bluetooth. I have already created a simple Activity that lists the nearby devices with bluetooth turned on but unfortunately I can't figure out how could I detect when some devices disappear from the bluetooth network (bt gets turned off) so that I could remove that item from the list.

This is my code I wrote to add nearby BT devices to a ListView:

```
mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new BluetoothDeviceArrayAdapter(this, 0, new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>());

lvDiscovered = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.bt_dev_discovered_list);
lvDiscovered.setAdapter(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);

...

// The BroadcastReceiver that listens for discovered devices and
// changes the title when discovery is finished
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          String action = intent.getAction();
          if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
              // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
              BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
              // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
              if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                  mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device);
              }
          // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
          } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
              // TODO show no devices found!
          }              
      }
  };
```

I found no applicable ACTION intent of the case when a device gets disappeared. Maybe ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED could be used, but how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to remove those devices from the list that was previously discovered.

Extending my code above I introduced an `update list` where I'm storing the newly discovered devices. When `ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED` appears I'll update the `ListView` with this update list.

```
...
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>   btDevicesUpdateList;
...

// The BroadcastReceiver that listens for discovered devices and
// changes the title when discovery is finished
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {                  
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
            // in the paired devices list
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                if(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0){
                   // if the list is empty we add the device immediately to it
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device);
                }
                btDevicesUpdateList.add(device);                      
             }
        }
        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
           mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.setItems(btDevicesUpdateList);
           btDevicesUpdateList.clear();
           mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
        }
    }
}  

// BluetoothDeviceArrayAdapter.java
public void setItems(ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> items){
    this.items.clear();
    this.items.addAll(items);
}
```

Devices that are unavailable will not be in the list.